# FTP upload error to create file Azure Devops create only .git folder

Tags: azure, build, ftp, azure-devops, yaml

I want to upload my public directory to my ftp server, I created to an Id and password in my vps, when I use

```
ftp -p xx.xx.xx.xx
```

And I connect with the user with the password, i'm connected, and i can create a folder with mkdir :

```
226 Directory send ok.
```

Now, I configured an azure devops pipeline to upload the content of y public folder to this ftp :

```
trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

steps:
- task: FtpUpload@2
  inputs:
    credentialsOption: 'inputs'
    serverUrl: 'ftp://xx.xx.xx.xx'
    username: 'xx'
    password: 'xx'
    rootDirectory: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)'
    filePatterns: '**'
    remoteDirectory: public
    preservePaths: true
    trustSSL: true
```

When i run the pipeline i get the following error **(very strange because it create the folders public, .git, but not the files)** :

```
connecting to: xx.xx.xx.xx:xxx
connected: 220 (vsFTPd 3.0.3)
files uploaded: 0, directories processed: 1, total: 1, remaining: 44084, remote directory successfully created/verified: public
```

files uploaded: 0, directories processed: 2, total: 2, remaining: 44083, remote directory successfully created/verified: public/.git
    ##[warning]FTPError: 553 Could not create file.
    connecting to: xx.xx.xx.xx:xxx
    connected: 220 (vsFTPd 3.0.3)
    ##[warning]FTPError: 553 Could not create file.
    connecting to: xx.xx.xx.xx:xxx
    connected: 220 (vsFTPd 3.0.3)
    ##[warning]FTPError: 553 Could not create file.
    connecting to: xx.xx.xx.xx:xxx
    connected: 220 (vsFTPd 3.0.3)
    ##[error]FTPError: 553 Could not create file.

```
host: xx.xx.xx.xx:xxx
path: public
files uploaded: 0
directories processed: 2
unprocessed files & directories: 64
##[error]Ftp Upload failed
disconnecting from: xx.xx.xx.xx:xxx
```

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

I ever encountered this error message.

For me, this error message caused by the folder where my **Uploaded File** task is going to upload to is owned by the `root` user, and can only be written by `root` by default. If other users need to upload files, permission restrictions and cannot be operated.

At this time, I create a new directory in the `ftp` directory, then use command `chmod` to set the permissions to 777use, thus it can also give **write** permission to other users.

Comment: Hello, I updated my post create another folder called public and changed permition to 77 to the user used for the ftp, now it create a folder public,a folder .Git but after it start to show the 553

Comment: @BenjaminBarbé Can I consider it as the file partly created successfully, right? Then the rest are all facing 530?

Comment: I have just an empty directory public/.git in my ftp but no files, unprocessed files & directories: 64, directories processed: 2, files uploaded: 0

Comment: @BenjaminBarbé did you have conf file under vsftpd？Add this into config file: `local_root=/var/ftp`. Then restart vsftpd: `service vsftpd restart` .

Comment: I have this file with local_root=/var/www/my-app because i want to have access only to this directly with this ftp user